# Не могу разобраться, при некоторых числах в переменной выводит не те данные

Tags: php, foreach

```
<?php
$dat = '1';
$mes = date('t');

$d=implode(',', range(1, $mes, 3));
$d2=implode(',', range(2, $mes, 3));
$d3=implode(',', range(3, $mes, 3));
echo $d.'<br>';
echo $d2.'<br>';
echo $d3.'<br>';
$res = explode(',', $d);
foreach ($res as $v) {
    if (intval($v) == $dat) $line='1';
    else 
            $res = explode(',', $d2);
        foreach ($res as $v) {
            if (intval($v) == $dat) $line='2';
            else 
            $res = explode(',', $d3);
        foreach ($res as $v) {
            if (intval($v) == $dat) $line='3';
            else ;
};
};
}
echo $line.'<br>';
?>
```

Когда $dat 1 или 2 все равно выводит что это $line='3'
А должны быть 1 и 2. Все остальные числа линий отрабатывают нормально.
В чем ошибка?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: смотри секциб debugging ↑↑↑